# Visual Studio - working out what code actually runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've inherited a Visual Studio 2005 C# project.

How can I tell which bits of code *actually* run?

It appears to have started life as a 'hello world' application for the original developer and over 15 years has morphed into company-critical system that runs 24-7. One consequence is that 90% of the code doesn't actually do anything.

How do I identify the 10% that actually does something? Ideally I'd like to leave the project running in the development environment for (say) 24 hours, and get a list of every function/method/procedure actually run in that period - then I can remove everything else.

The long term idea is to upgrade to something newer, but rather than upgrading 90% unused code I'd prefer to start by trimming the application down to the bare essentials.

UPDATE - the code not used by any other projects - so that shouldn't be a problem.
Thanks for 'profiler' tip it's amazing how much easier problems are to solve once you have that one word you need to google for!

Comment: What you are looking for is called a *profiler*. Microsoft has included a profile with its top-end Visual Studio editions at times over the years - but I don't know if it's there any more

Comment: Your plan won't necessarily work because execution paths can be dependent on inputs any your test may not exercise all paths. Visual Studio will tell you what members have no references, but that is also a gamble if  the code is used by other projects.

Comment: Cutting code based on profiling alone is a risky proposition. Sort of "*my neighbor has a boat in the garage which he hasn't used since I moved here 3 months ago, so he certainly doesn't need it*" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see what code actually runs. The Runtime Summary window in particular lists all classes and functions that were used during a program run organized by modules and namespaces:

[image]